# how to inject JQuery into a D7 page

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a Drupal 7 view page where I want to change the behaviour of the submit button by using the jQuery code below. How do I do this in Drupal 7?

```
$('#reset-button').click(function() {
  $('#views-exposed-form').each(function() {
    this.reset();
  });
  $('#submit-button').click();

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add your code in a JS file say somescript.js and save it in your theme folder. In the theme.info file add the following line

```
scripts[] = somescript.js
```

This will add `somescript.js` to all pages by default. If you want it for a particular page add a conditional check and use `drupal_add_js(PATH_TO_JS)` 
For more info check out [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722)

Comment: WhiteMonk's point about adding the context wrapper around the code is important too. Also a good idea is to use behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

To use `$` you have to introduce

```
jQuery(function($) {});
```

at the begining.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#reset-button').click(function() {
       $('#views-exposed-form').each(function() {
         this.reset();
        });
       $('#submit-button').click();

       return false;
      });
     });
 });
```

To add this js file to a page you have to use

```
 drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name').'/path/to/js');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to write a whole new module to inject custom JavaScript code, then try this module http://drupal.org/project/js_injector.

I have been using this module from long time and it works beautifully.

Answer (score -1):

Good idea! Regarding this I found painless solution. I installed jQuerify from here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquerify/gbmifchmngifmadobkcpijhhldeeelkc
It injects jQuery 1.8 even in HTTPS pages with one click  with no conflict to Prototype )))

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question in any way...